# File not found error in bridging header file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have an objective-c project. It is about two years that I am working on it. Now I want to do new works with Swift.

I added a new Swift class. Xcode asked me to add BridggingHeader file and I pressed YES.

but now in the bridging header file I want to import my current objective-c classed but this file do not recongize my objective-c files.

For example when I write:

```
#import "MYBaseViewController.h"
```

xcode shows error and says:

```
MYBaseViewController.h file not found
```

Comment: Do you have multiple targets?

Comment: Yes I have two targets

Comment: Make sure its "MyBaseViewController" and not "MYBaseViewController". See "y" vs "Y".

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that bridging header is set correctly for each target by going to Build Settings.
2. Make sure that the file is included in both targets. Select it in the Project Navigator and then open File Inspector and check target Membership section:

[image]

Comment: I checked the path for both of them and they are set correctly

Comment: @HuseinBehbudiRad what about file membership? Is it included in both targets?

Comment: @HuseinBehbudiRad select file and then open File Inspector. I will update my answer now

Comment: Yes, under target membership I can see both my targets

Comment: @HuseinBehbudiRad is there any chance you can upload source code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87701/discussion-between-andriy-gordiychuk-and-husein-behbudirad).

Comment: @Husein Behboodi .make sure your bridging path is set correctly.if it not set then set bridging path .It will work fine for you.